# for each dir create a tar file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a bunch of directories that need to be restored, but they have to first be packaged into a .tar. Is there a script that would allow me to package all 100+ directories into their own tar so dir becomes dir.tar.

So far attempt:

```
for i in *; do tar czf $i.tar $i; done
```

Comment: If there's a way of listing them explicitly ... yes.

Comment: They are alone in their own dir if that helps to make it possible.

Comment: What tink probably meant to tell you is that SO is not a "write my scripts for me" site. What have you tried so far?

Comment: What's the problem with the script you have?

Answer (score 82):

The script that you wrote will not work if you have some spaces in a directory name, because the name will be split, and also it will tar files if they exist on this level.

You can use this command to list directories not recursively:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d
```

and this one to perform a tar on each one:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -exec tar cvf {}.tar {}  \;
```

Comment: Add `` to remove the original directories once archived: `find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -exec tar cvf {}.tar {} --remove-files \;`

Comment: compress `find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -exec tar zcvf {}.tar.gz {}  \;`

Comment: The `-mindepth 1` is important too, otherwise the first thing you'll process is `.`, the current directory.

Comment: any trick to ignore specific folder/s?

Answer (score 7):

Do you have any directory names with spaces in them at that level? If not, your script will work just fine.

What I usually do is write a script with the command I want to execute echoed out:

```
$ for i in *
do
    echo tar czf $i.tar $i
done
```

Then you can look at the output and see if it's doing what you want. After you've determined that the program will work, edit the command line and remove the `echo` command.

Answer (score 4):

If there are spaces in the directory names, then just put the variables inside double quotes:

```
for i in *
 do
     tar czf "$i.tar" "$i"
 done
```

Answer (score 3):

Get them all done simply and in parallel with **GNU Parallel**:

```
parallel tar -cf {}.tar {} ::: *
```

If you want to check what it is going to do without actually doing anything, add `--dry-run` like this:

```
parallel --dry-run tar -cf {}.tar {} ::: *
```

**Sample Output**

```
tar -cf ab.tar ab
tar -cf cd.tar cd
```

Answer (score 1):

if number of directories are very large and their names are too long

after execution of statement number one

```
  for i in *
    do
     echo tar czf $i.tar $i
    done
```

you will get error "string too long"